# How to add scroll bar or something like that, in data grid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm having trouble with showing text in my project. 
I have MsSQL DB linked into my WPF application via Datagrid.
One of columns in my DB is called "Popis" (Description) and it's a text type, so I could show larger text.
Thing is, that I can't find a way how to show it all. Window is static and columns are non-resizable.
Is there any way how to add a scroll bar, some pop up window or anything, that allow me to show all of its content?

Thanks for any advice!

Illustration image https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5r29.jpg

Comment: Have you tried setting `DataGrid.ColumnWidth = DataGridLength.SizeToCells`? What have you tried?

Comment: Theoretically this should work, but you don't want to end up with long horizontal scroll. This is not user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make your data grid row height to "*" and add expender control inside the cell, or have two values for the cell (one short description and one full description), and display short description in cell and tooltip full description). Reference on how to do tooltip inside the cell, you can find at the post below (item number 4)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/04/07/5-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx

Hope this helps